# sql server log shipping: how to monitor that the replica is fresh? (e.g. that log shipping is working)

Tags: sql-server

I want a monitor on my replica (destination) server to message me:

a) once a day, telling me: "Data as of  is ### minutes old"

b) any time data is older than N minutes (indicating log shipping has gone down)

I typically have tlogs moving every 5 minutes, on a very active database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> a) once a day, telling me: "Data as of is ### minutes old"

You have to  get the status using  `master..sp_help_log_shipping_monitor` to get the status. There are many scripts available that will send out HTML email through SQL Agent job like

- [Get an overview report on your log shipping setups](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/12/21/get-an-overview-report-on-your-log-shipping-setups.aspx)
- [Logshipping status report Throgh Mail](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1259335-391-1.aspx)
- [Automating SQL Server Transactional Log Shipping Alerts](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2012/automating-sql-server-transactional-log-shipping-alerts/)

> b) any time data is older than N minutes (indicating log shipping has gone down)

The job LSAlert_XX where XX is the instance name, run a job  `exec sys.sp_check_log_shipping_monitor_alert` to check if the restore of the log has fallen behind **N mins**. You can edit/configure it to send out emails in case where it has fallen behind **N mins**.